# Kendo grid - how to make whole row selection navigetable by UP/DOWN keyboard keys?

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, keyboard-events

I have the following grid with coloured row after the mouse click on the selected row.

[image]

I would like to add the same functionality if user will using UP and DOWN rows on the keyboard with event where actual selected row by keyboard will be passed like in the change function below.

How can i do it please using the Kendo?

```
change: function (e) {
              var selectedRows = this.select();
              var selectedDataItems = [];
              for (var i = 0; i < selectedRows.length; i++) {
                  var dataItem = this.dataItem(selectedRows[i]);
                  selectedDataItems.push(dataItem);
              }
              console.log(selectedDataItems);
              $scope.setDetailToScope(selectedDataItems, "row_select");
          },
```

**Edit:**

I tried this function too:

```
$(function () {
    var arrows = [38, 40];
    var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
    grid.table.on("keydown", function (e) {
        if (arrows.indexOf(e.keyCode) >= 0) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                grid.select($("#rowSelection_active_cell").closest("tr"));
            });
        }
    })
});
```

Up/Down button is recognized but i cannot get the next selected row and colorize it.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply enable Kendo `navigatable` feature:

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
    ...
    selectable: "row",
    navigatable: true,
    ...
});
```

Similarly to: http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/keyboard-navigation

EDIT:
To navigate without ghost highlighting you should manually handle this:

```
  var data = $("#grid").data('kendoGrid');
  var arrows = [38, 40];
  data.table.on("keydown", function (e) {
    if (arrows.indexOf(e.keyCode) >= 0) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            data.select($("#grid_active_cell").closest("tr"));
        },1);
    }
  }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/bzm5dwvo/

Comment: Thanks, i have values You mentioned already set in the grid config, but it is working only on the cells, not for whole row and it doest not firing the change function.

Comment: Standard behavior of this feature requires to confirm using space after selecting cell. After it, whole row should be highlighted.

Comment: Is possible to override this default behavior?

Comment: Result is same. Could You post JsFiddle snippet please?

Comment: JsFiddle throwing error Uncaught TypeError: $(...).kendoGrid is not a function

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75818/discussion-between-suvroc-and-redrom).

Answer (score 0):

you must set grid `Selectable` and `GridSelectionMode` set `Single`
like :

```
.Selectable(s=> s.Mode(GridSelectionMode.Single))
```

and you can use `Navigate` envent in grid events :

`.Events(evt=> evt.Navigate("navigate"));`

and in js function :

```
function navigate(e) {
    var grid = e.sender;
    grid.select(grid.tbody.find(e.element.parent()));
}
```